# Jabber integration into site and multiple domains

Tags: web-services, integration, xmpp, instant-messaging

I'm creating a centralised web product, i.e. a customer gets assigned a personal domain, for example company1.example.com or company2.example.com and can then use our service.

I'm planning to integrate a jabber service into the website. I have already found a decent jabber client library which I can use for the site.

I know that jabberd2 uses mysql, which is perfect because I want to use the web interface to add users, delete users, view message logs etc.

However, my problem is when I have two companies or more. I would like a jabber server which can host multiple domains, i.e. jabber.company1.example.com, jabber.company2.example.com

Do you have any experience of this? And do you know of a good jabber server which will do this?  Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at ejabberd. It supports multiple domains, and has a good reputation in production. It also seems to support MySQL, even though we're using it with its own database. Don't know what your overall infrastructure is, and if you can run erlang, but overall it seems like a good match for your requirements.